# Travel telescope: attaching a Lunt 80mm ed on a Dolica tripod

Tags: telescope

I'm assembling a compact and light travel telescope. I'm going for the small [Lunt 80mm ed](https://luntsolarsystems.com/product/lunt-ed-doublet-optical-tube-assemblies/) refractor telescope mounted on a light [Dolica tripod](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004XC3GZW).  For those with this --or similar-- assembly, I would like to ask you how did you attach the Lunt to the Dolica.

Thanks,
Marcelo

Comment: The Dolica appears to come with a ball head.  In my experience ball heads are not ideal for astronomical use because there is usually quite a bit of play in the mount, and also as you slacken the ball, the telescope tends to slip over unpredictably.